# Where clause not respected?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem that a where clause in my query is not respected. This is the query I am using:

```
Capsule::table('tblhosting')
        ->select('*','tbldomains.nextduedate as domainnextduedate' , 'tblhosting.nextduedate as hostingnextduedate')
        ->join('tblclients', 'tblhosting.userid', '=', 'tblclients.id')
        ->join('tbldomains', 'tblhosting.domain', '=', 'tbldomains.domain')
        ->where('tblhosting.nextduedate', '!=', 'tbldomains.nextduedate')
        ->where('tbldomains.status', '=', 'Active')
        ->where('tblhosting.termination_date', '=', '0000-00-00')               
        ->get()
```

If I do a vardump, I get these values:

```
    [56] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 406
        [userid] => 9
        [orderid] => 730
        [packageid] => 35
        [server] => 9
        [regdate] => 2016-12-23
        [domain] => xxx.net
        [paymentmethod] => banktransfer
        [firstpaymentamount] => 0.00
        [amount] => 0.00
        [billingcycle] => Annually
        [nextduedate] => 2017-12-23
        [nextinvoicedate] => 2017-12-23
        [termination_date] => 0000-00-00
        [completed_date] => 0000-00-00
        [domainstatus] => Active            
        [domainnextduedate] => 2017-12-23
        [hostingnextduedate] => 2017-12-23
    )
```

As you can see, tbldomains.nextduedate and tbldomains.nextduedate are both '2017-12-23', so they shouldn't have been returned, since I use

```
->where('tblhosting.nextduedate', '!=', 'tbldomains.nextduedate')
```

I thought it could be because I use aliases, but when I try

```
->where('domainnextduedate', '!=', 'hostingnextduedate')
```

I get a PDO error:

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'domainnextduedate' in 'where clause''
```

I am not sure what I am missing..

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that the time components are different?  Also, what is your intention in comparing a date against `0000-00-00`?  This seems meaningless to me.

Comment: I have checked the structure, and both are in standard 'date' formate. Only difference is that for 1 the default value is 0000-00-00, and for the other default value is NULL. But this should not make a difference as all are filled in.
I guess you mean "where('tblhosting.termination_date', '=', '0000-00-00') ". If that field is 0000-00-00, then the hosting package is not terminated. If it contains a value, it is terminated.

Comment: What are the types of the `nextduedate` columns in the 2 tables?

Comment: They are both DATE type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give this code a try:

```
->whereColumn('tblhosting.nextduedate', '!=', 'tbldomains.nextduedate')
```

Comment: With pleasure.. Remember that the usual 'where' clauses regard the third parameter as a string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is instead of believing the right column is a column, it parses it as a string, so the result of the where is gonna be parsed to `2017-12-23 = tbldomains.nextduedate`. To work around this you have to use `whereRaw`.

```
->whereRaw('tblhosting.nextduedate <> tbldomains.nextduedate')
```

**EDIT**

In Laravel you use whereDate, when dealing with dates in queries. So your Query should look something like this:

```
->whereDate('tblhosting.nextduedate', '!=', 'tbldomains.nextduedate')
```

Comment: I tried this: ->whereDate('tblhosting.nextduedate', '!=', 'tbldomains.nextduedate'), but still the same i'm afraid

Comment: Have you tried printing out the query log? DB::enableQueryLog();
DB::getQueryLog()

Comment: That returns:
            [query] => select *, `tbldomains`.`nextduedate` as `domainnextduedate`, `tblhosting`.`nextduedate` as `hostingnextduedate`, `tbldomains`.`id` as `domainid`, `tblhosting`.`id` as `hostingid` from `tblhosting` inner join `tblclients` on `tblhosting`.`userid` = `tblclients`.`id` inner join `tbldomains` on `tblhosting`.`domain` = `tbldomains`.`domain` where date(`tblhosting`.`nextduedate`) != ?
            [bindings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => tbldomains.nextduedate
                )

            [time] => 9.77
        )

Comment: Since the where clause gets translated to where date(`tblhosting`.`nextduedate`) != ?, it makes sense that it does nog get respected. Howevern I don't get why `tbldomains`.`nextduedate` is changed to ?

Comment: Oh the problem is the right side is not loaded as a column but as a string, let me think.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it helps :)